# Loop is not reaching 100

Tags: python

I am not getting why my score not reaching 100 and breaking out

**Code:**

```
flag = 0 

while True:
 
  p1 = 0

  if flag == 0:

    p1_d = random.randint(1, 6)
    p1_s = p1 + p1_d # 0 + 3  : 3 
    p1 = p1 + p1_d

    print(p1_s)

    if p1_s == 100:
      print(p1_s)
      break
```

The `p1_s` value is not reaching `100`

Following is the Output I am getting

```
1
2
3
1
5
1
2
3
1
5
```

if flag is zero it will enter into
if condition keep adding the random values , until it reaches 100 and break

I want to write a code which could take random value and keep incrementing until it reach max 100 and exit code

Comment: What *is* it printing?

Comment: @BeRT2me  : its printing values between 1 till 6 but never my `p1_s` get incremented and reach max value 100

Comment: Could you add some details? What is the variable `flag`? Is it relevant in your example, or could it be removed? Also, what do you get as output?

Comment: @BlackBeans : updated question please check

Comment: You're setting `p1 = 0` on every loop

Answer (score 2):

This will solve your purpose of making `p1_s` reach 100.

```
import random

flag = 0
p1 = 0 # You need to move this outside of the while loop
while True:
  if flag == 0:
    p1_d = random.randint(1, 6)
    p1_s = p1 + p1_d # 0 + 3  : 3 
    p1 = p1 + p1_d

    print(p1_s)

    if p1_s >= 100: # Also, check for greater than 100
      print(p1_s)
      break
```

Sample Output:

```
4
9
13
14
19
25
27
33
39
45
50
53
59
63
64
67
70
75
81
84
86
87
91
93
96
100
100
```

### What you were doing wrong?

1. Setting `p1 = 0` on every loop or iteration and this is why `p1` was getting reset to 0.
2. Checking for `p1_s == 0` instead of `p1_s >= 100`. This will check if `p1_s` is greater than or equal to 100. Since you are adding a random integer to `p1_s` every time it's highly unlikely that `p1_s` will be equal to 100.

Answer (score 0):

Let's track a couple times in the loop:

1. p1 = 0
2. p1_d = 5 *lets say 5 this time*
3. p1_s = 0 + 5 = 5
4. p1 = 0 + 5 = 5
5. prints p1_s (5)
6. p1_s isn't 100

...

7. p1 = 0
8. p1_d = 3 *lets say 3 this time*
9. p1_s = 0 + 3
10. p1 = 0 + 3
11. prints p1_s (3)
12. p1_s isn't 100

...

Have you seen the issue yet?

Comment: : I want to take random value and keep adding it until it reaches 100 , if reaches 100 exit code. This I am currently looking for

Comment: `p1_s` is `p1 + p1_d`, `p1` is ALWAYS 0 at this point, because you reset it every loop, so you'll never have a value larger than 5.

Answer (score 0):

**I see you are setting p1 = 0 in every iteration. Hence it is impossible for it to reach a 100 because it will always be of the value of random number**

(But even if it is remove)
You are adding random numbers again and again. `p1_s` will always be of greater value than it was an iteration before.

There is no guarantee that it will become 100 in increments. Also, at it is incrementing without any condition if exactly 100 didn't occur it will run forever to an infinite iterations. Probability of getting exactly 100 by these random increments is very very low.

I don't know what you want to achieve but try considering alternate method for what you are doing or try adding some condition that are more likely to occur(keeping your actual problem in mind)